# Restrict a user to click a button only 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a game to my website. The game starts when they click a button. The intention is that users can play the game **daily** only 3 times.  Also when they refresh the page, they are not allowed to play the game again.

Do I have to restrict this by IP-adress?

I got the ip-adress with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
        ipAdres = data.ip;
        console.log("Your ip: " + ipAdres);
    });
});
```

Or are there other ways to restrict a user from clicking a button daily only 3 times?

Comment: where is the button here?

Comment: You can only do this on the serverside, so you should be posting the serverside code ?

Comment: I don't have more code, because i don't know what the process is, to restrict a user to click a button only 3 times....

Comment: Its not important that ip address is going to remain same every time user visit website

Comment: He can go over a proxy server than you're lost

Comment: Could you use a jquery cookies to handle this, just increment the value until 3 and make the cookie last only 1 day. Of course users can reset their cookies, in that case only keeping it on the server side.

Comment: There is no secure way to do this. IP certainly is not an option, since multiple users can use the same IP address. Cookies or other means of identification can be suppressed, faked or manipulated. In general it is a bad habit of programmers to decide for the user. Let the user decide what he wants to do.

Comment: Why not have a login?

Comment: @DanWhite Yes i agree with you, only on the server side with a generated unique-id.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is keep an flag in database with count name and let the user play game when count is less then or equal to three and when user is playing game, update count with count+1

This is most feasible solution for this as Ip address keep on changing